# Screen goes grey after coming back from Sleep

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, sleep

I've been getting a strange error lately. When I put my computer in sleep mode and recover from it, the screen goes gray. I am then obligated to force-reboot (holding the power button) my computer. Also occasionally, when restarting (50% of the time) the computer at that moment, I get the Boot Error blue screen. See images.

I have no clue what causes this. I have ran a Windows Update check, and it's all good. Same for antivirus. I also ran on Cmd

```
SFC /SCANNOW
```

But it returned everything was OK.

I'm lost! What could be the next steps?

IMAGES:

[image: blue screen]

[image: gray screen]

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps given below :

1. Power on your computer.
2. Enter into BIOS Setup.
3. Go to **Boot** Tab.
4. Highlight **Boot Mode**, press **Enter**, swap from "**UEFI**" to "**Legacy Support**". Under that Swap UEFI to legacy First
5. Go to **EXIT** tab and highlight **Exit saving changes**. Press **Enter**.

Comment: Hi that does not work. When I boot the computer then, I get the error "No Bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

Comment: You need to boot from Windows 10 installation media or recovery disc, then select repair your computer. Then follow this guide to fix https://malwaretips.com/threads/how-to-fix-no-bootable-device-%E2%80%93-insert-boot-disk-and-press-any-key.8907/